# Files and folders are copied as shortcuts to flash drive

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

When I'm copying folders and files from my internal hard disk to the flash drive and the opposite, the folders and files are copied as a shortcut instead.

Avira Antivirus hasn't found anything.

How can I get the default behavior back?

Comment: This doesn't sound like any virus I've come across. How are you copying them? Copy & paste? click & drag?

Comment: Why are you so sure it's a virus? I've removed that part of the question as it could be misleading. Does it happen with all flash drives or just a specific one?

Comment: @Msaleh - You really need to provide more information.  What you describe is unlikely a virus.

Answer (score 0):

My netbook did this before - I could not copy from my desktop to a folder on my desktop (it created shortcuts) and a system restore solved it.